# Android Fragment Button

Tags: android, button, navigation, fragment

I am creating a simple application which will have a bottom navigation view.

This will take the user between various categories. This has been setup with Fragments and a case system

I then want buttons on these category pages which take you to other pages with the navigation at bottom of each of the pages.

When I put my button code I used on the previous version of this application it fails saying 
`error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)`

After some reading I can see this doesnt work with fragments but I cant find anything clear or easy to understand as to how to make these work.

In short, i would like the nav panel to stay constant on any page i load not just the category pages i have listed in the panel.

Any of the letter pages and other links from buttons need to open in the panel above the nav bar but i have no clue how to implement this.

Any help would be ... helpful. I have spent about 12 hours trying various things with no avail.

[image]

**Code to handle navigation fragments:**

```
package breed.sheep.british.com.britishsheepbreeds;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import breed.sheep.british.com.britishsheepbreeds.fragment.BreedsFragment;
import breed.sheep.british.com.britishsheepbreeds.fragment.ColoursFragment;
import breed.sheep.british.com.britishsheepbreeds.fragment.DefaultFragment;
import breed.sheep.british.com.britishsheepbreeds.fragment.TerminologyFragment;
import breed.sheep.british.com.britishsheepbreeds.fragment.TypeFragment;
import breed.sheep.british.com.britishsheepbreeds.helper.BottomNavigationBehavior;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ActionBar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = getSupportActionBar();

    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    BottomNavigationBehavior.disableShiftMode(navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);




    // attaching bottom sheet behaviour - hide / show on scroll
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) navigation.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.setBehavior(new BottomNavigationBehavior());

    // load the default fragment
    toolbar.setTitle("British Sheep Breeds");
    loadFragment(new DefaultFragment());
}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.home:
                toolbar.setTitle("British Sheep Breeds");
                fragment = new DefaultFragment();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                return true;
            case R.id.breeds:
                toolbar.setTitle("Breeds A-Z");
                fragment = new BreedsFragment();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                return true;
            case R.id.colour:
                toolbar.setTitle("Colours");
                fragment = new ColoursFragment();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                return true;
            case R.id.type:
                toolbar.setTitle("Type ");
                fragment = new TypeFragment();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                return true;
            case R.id.term:
                toolbar.setTitle("Terminology ");
                fragment = new TerminologyFragment();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                return true;


        }

        return false;
    }
};

/**
 * loading fragment into FrameLayout
 *
 * @param fragment
 */
private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    // load fragment
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
} }
```

**Fragment page**

```
package breed.sheep.british.com.britishsheepbreeds.fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import breed.sheep.british.com.britishsheepbreeds.R;


public class DefaultFragment extends Fragment {

    public DefaultFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static DefaultFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        DefaultFragment fragment = new DefaultFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,

                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }
}
```

**previous button code**

```
Button balwen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.balwen);
        balwen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), balwen.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                    }


                });
```

Comment: You might want to add the button code to each specific fragment and run the do something similar to what you're doing on the main page for the navigations, so in general: in each fragment layout, out the button and in their class call the button  from onCreateView properly, then you can out the navigation code inside the onclick function. I hope it might help you.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, are you able to elaborate?

Comment: You want buttons on each category page, and that means you will put the button in each page and perform your click functions, and I said for the cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
You might be call the button from the wrong place, so call the buttons from the onCreate view on each fragment, Give me few minutes let me write a sample code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button balwenLeft, balwenRight;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
Fragment fragment;

public Timeline() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static Timeline newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    Timeline fragment = new Timeline();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
    fragmentManager = this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_colours, container, false);

    fragment = new FirstPageOnBreedFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.channelactivitycontainer, fragment).commit();

    balwenLeft = (Button) l.findViewById(R.id.btnLeft);
    balwenLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            fragment = new AnotherFragmentWithInBreedFrag();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        }
    });

    balwenRight = (Button) l.findViewById(R.id.btnRight);
    balwenRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            fragment = new AnotherFragmentWithInBreedFrag();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        }
    });

    return l;
```

> > So this looks like what you might want to do, what's actually happening is that from each fragment as a category, you will create the custom navigations buttons on the layouts and when calling it from the fragment,
> >     Don't forget that you will need to inflate the layouts of the fragment like i did, the parent layout of the fragment layout is `LinearLayout` in my case, so if you're using Relating layout or Coor... just change them respectively, and back to the navigations, what's happening is that I'm hard coding it but you can replace it with your switch case function that's actually simpler, so if you're on BreedsFragment, You will have two Buttons that will help you navigate between the pages in BreedFrag... In general we're just replacing whatever is present in `frame_container` just like the bottom nav does, same thing happens when you click the buttons but in this case you'r still on the same page breedFrag, and note that i'm assuming the those pages are also fragements. I hope you understand, else if you can share your code on gitHub I can help contribute to it.